# Javascript Load HTML Page into new window and print

Tags: javascript

I am quite new to javascript. I want to load a html page into new window and print that page. The page is successfully loaded. But it only prints a blank page. (Test with MS XPS document writer)
Here is my code..

```
var newWin=window.open("Home.html","_blank","menubar=0,resizable=1,width=320,height=320");
            newWin.focus();                                         
            newWin.print();
        newWin.close();
```

Comment: I know what your issue is and it's actually very simple to resolve. First before I answer, do you have control on the contents of your html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a load handler on the new window so print won;t start until page is loaded

```
newWin.onload=function(){
    newWin.focus();                                         
    newWin.print();
    newWin.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: The content that you're trying to print might not have loaded fully yet when the print command is issued, so by wrapping it in a timer, you force the print to be placed at the end of the execution queue.

```
var newWin = window.open("Home.html","_blank","menubar=0,resizable=1,width=320,height=320");
setTimeout(function() {
    newWin.focus();                                         
    newWin.print();
    newWin.close();
}, 1);
```